# How to get words after specific words in Python

Tags: python

How can I get words after 'Pickup Location', 'External Identifier', 'Location' etc

```
Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identiﬁer: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
Barcode: 
Title: Liberalism and the postcolony : thinking the state in 20th-century Philippines /
Library: Geisel Library
Location: Books Floor5
Call Number: DS685 .C57 2017
Author: Claudio, Lisandro E.,
UC San Diego Library Contact Us
```

This doesn't seem to work

```
external_spl_word = 'External Identifier: '
res = text.split(external_spl_word)[0]
external_splitString = res[0]
external_splitString = text[text.find(external_spl_word)+len(external_spl_word):]
print("External Identifier: ", external_splitString)
```

I have tried using `external_splitString = text[text.find(external_spl_word) + len(external_spl_word):]` too

Comment: What is the exact output or result that you want here?

Comment: `res = text.split(external_spl_word)[0]` This will split the text into two parts: everything _before_ "External Identifier", and everything _after_ that.  And since you're using the first element of the result, `res` is equal to everything _before_.

Comment: expected output is ''ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation'' for Pickup Location, ''580978'' for External Identifier, etc. The first whole block is type string.

Comment: How are you receiving the data you would like split?

Comment: where does this text data resides, is it coming from a file having multiple lines as you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

First you can split the text using your `external_spl_word` as a delimiter using `.split()` function, then extract the desired words after `external_spl_word` using appropriate index or the `.split()` function again.

```
text = """
Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identifier: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
Barcode:
Title: Liberalism and the postcolony : thinking the state in 20th-century Philippines /
Library: Geisel Library
Location: Books Floor5
Call Number: DS685 .C57 2017
Author: Claudio, Lisandro E.,
UC San Diego Library Contact Us
"""


# external_spl_word = 'Pickup Location: '
# external_spl_word = 'External Identifier: '
external_spl_word = 'Requested Bar code: '
external_splitString = text.split(external_spl_word)[1].split('\n')[0]
print(f"{external_spl_word}{external_splitString}")
```

You can uncomment each line of `external_spl_word` to have individual output.

Output:

```
Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identifier: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
```

Answer (score 0):

RegExp is probably the best option here. Use a pattern to discern the keys and values in each line and parse them to a data structure of your choosing:

```
import re

data = """Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identiﬁer: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
Barcode: 
Title: Liberalism and the postcolony : thinking the state in 20th-century Philippines /
Library: Geisel Library
Location: Books Floor5
Call Number: DS685 .C57 2017
Author: Claudio, Lisandro E.,
UC San Diego Library Contact Us
"""

parsed = re.findall(r'^(?P<key>[^:]+): (?P<value>.*(?=$))', data, re.M)
print(parsed)
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/TreasuredConsiderateSystemsanalysis#main.py) | [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rqtn52/1)</sup>

The advantage of this specific RegExp approach is that you won't have to know the key names in advance; simply having assurance that the format always follows `key: value\nkey: value` is enough to be able to dynamically extract the data as you seem to desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
text="""Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identiﬁer: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
Barcode: 
Title: Liberalism and the postcolony : thinking the state in 20th-century Philippines /
Library: Geisel Library
Location: Books Floor5
Call Number: DS685 .C57 2017
Author: Claudio, Lisandro E., UC San Diego Library Contact Us"""

text_liist = text.split("\n")
text_dict = dict(t.split(":", maxsplit=1) for t in map(str.strip, text_liist))

print(text_dict.get("Title"))
print(text_dict.get("External Identiﬁer"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use regex:

```
import re

data = """Pickup Location: ccirc:USD-COPLEY :USD Copley Circulation
External Identiﬁer: 580978
Requested Bar code: 31822044004612
Barcode: 
Title: Liberalism and the postcolony : thinking the state in 20th-century Philippines /
Library: Geisel Library
Location: Books Floor5
Call Number: DS685 .C57 2017
Author: Claudio, Lisandro E.,
UC San Diego Library Contact Us"""

pickup_location = re.search("Pickup Location: (.*)", data).group(1)
external_itentifier = re.search("External Identiﬁer: (.*)", data).group(1)
print(pickup_location)
print(external_itentifier)
```

If you would like to learn more about using regex with Python, check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp